# Rendering open gl es view in react native

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, react-native

I'm trying to render an opengl es native component within a react native app. At the moment I have a blank screen where i expected to see a red rectangle using glClearColor. There are no errors when the code is run.
I'm new to objective c so there are some syntax idiosyncrasies i may have gotten wrong. But here is what i have so far.

my-custom-view-manager.h

```
#import "RCTViewManager.h"

@interface myCustomViewManager : RCTViewManager

@end
```

my-custom-view-manager.m

```
#import "myCustomViewManager.h"
#import "myCustomView.h"

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@implementation myCustomViewManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (UIView *)view
{
  myCustomView * v;
  v = [[myCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  return v;
}

@end
```

my-custom-view.h

```
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>


@interface myCustomView : GLKView {
  EAGLContext *context;
}

@end
```

my-custom-view.m

```
#import "myCustomView.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@implementation myCustomView

+ (Class)layerClass {
  return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

  if (self) {
    CAEAGLLayer *EAGLLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *) super.layer;
    EAGLLayer.opaque = YES;

    context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    if (!context ||  ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context]) {
      NSLog(@"No context");
      exit(1);
    }

    GLuint framebuffer, renderbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &framebuffer);
    glGenBuffers(1, &renderbuffer);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffer);

    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_FRAMEBUFFER fromDrawable:EAGLLayer];

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffer);

    glViewport(0, 0, 200, 200);

    [self render];

  }
  return self;
}

- (void)render
{
  glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}

@end
```

Can anyone help out and help me get this to render something.

Thanks

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few calls in your code are wrong. You should check some working example.

Anyway these are the lines that need changing:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer); // change function
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderbuffer); // change function
[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:EAGLLayer]; // Convert to GL_RENDERBUFFER
```

But generally this is not a `GLKView` procedure. Simply use `UIView` as a parent class.

To be more safe try to implement something as following:

```
- (void)initializeBuffers
{
    CAEAGLLayer *layer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;
    layer.opaque = YES;
    layer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    GLuint frameBuffer = 0;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    self.frameBuffer = frameBuffer;

    GLuint renderBuffer = 0;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer);
    self.renderBuffer = renderBuffer;

    [_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:layer];
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer);

    GLint bufferSize[2] = {0,0};
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, bufferSize);
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, bufferSize+1);
    self.bufferWidth = bufferSize[0];
    self.bufferHeight = bufferSize[1];

    if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        NSLog(@"Error creating framebuffer (error %d)", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, self.bufferWidth, self.bufferHeight);
}
```